# Align column content to the right of cell React MUIDataTable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to MUI and i want to align the content of a column to the right.my code looks like this:

```
<MUIDataTable
  title={""}
  data={data || []}
  columns={realColumns ? realColumns(data, modeMO) : columns(data, modeMO)}
  options={{
    filterType: "textField",
    responsive: "simple",
    selectableRows: selectable, // set checkbox for each row
    search: false, // set search option
    filter: false, // set data filter option
    download: false, // set download option
    print: false, // set print option
    pagination: true, //set pagination option
    viewColumns: false, // set column option
    elevation: 0,
    rowsPerPageOptions: [10, 20, 40, 80, 100],
    //setCellProps: () => ({ align: 'right' }) ,
    onRowSelectionChange: (
      currentRowsSelected,
      allRowsSelected,
      rowsSelected
    ) => {
      setSelectedRows(
        allRowsSelected.map((el) => {
          return data[el.dataIndex];
        })
      );
    },
    selectToolbarPlacement: "none"
  }}
/>;
```

and this is what's displayed:
[table Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTzTL.png)

so i would like to align all the numbers in "Montant à régler" column to the right.
can somebody help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is totally un-tested and only a snip of "columns".

Give your columns a custom render and set the cell properties i.e. something like:

```js
export const columns = [
    {
        name: "category",
        label: "Fun Guy Category",
        options: {
            setCellProps: () => ({ style: { minWidth: "100px", maxWidth: "800px", justifyContent: 'end'  }}),
            customBodyRender: (data, type, row) => {return <pre>{data}</pre>}
      },
    },
```

Comment: thanks alot! man it did work for me with some modifications:                                 
 setCellProps: () => ({ style: { minWidth: "100px", maxWidth: "800px",display:"flex",alignitems:'end', justifyContent: 'end',backgroundColor:'orange'  }})

Answer (score 1):

If you are using basic tables of Material UI then you can align it through passing **align** prop to the TableCells to align content in each row and column. You can set **align** equals to right, left, etc.

If you are using DataGrid or data tables of Material UI (Which I think you are) then you can pass align prop to each column. See the edited example code below from Material UI:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const columns = [
{ field: "id", align: "rights", headerName: "ID", width: 70 },
{ field: "firstName", align: "center", headerName: "First name", 
width: 130 },
{ field: "lastName", align: "left", headerName: "Last name", 
width: 130 },
{
field: "age",
headerName: "Age",
type: "number",
width: 90
},
{
field: "fullName",
headerName: "Full name",
description: "This column has a value getter and is not 
sortable.",
sortable: false,
width: 160,
valueGetter: (params) =>
  `${params.getValue(params.id, "firstName") || ""} ${
    params.getValue(params.id, "lastName") || ""
  }`
}
];

const rows = [
{ id: 1, align: "right", lastName: "Snow", firstName: "Jon", age: 
35 },
{ id: 2, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Cersei", age: 42 },
{ id: 3, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Jaime", age: 45 },
{ id: 4, lastName: "Stark", firstName: "Arya", age: 16 },
{ id: 5, lastName: "Targaryen", firstName: "Daenerys", age: null 
},
{ id: 6, lastName: "Melisandre", firstName: null, age: 150 },
{ id: 7, lastName: "Clifford", firstName: "Ferrara", age: 44 },
{ id: 8, lastName: "Frances", firstName: "Rossini", age: 36 },
{ id: 9, lastName: "Roxie", firstName: "Harvey", age: 65 }
];

export default function DataTable() {
return (
<div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
  <DataGrid
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    pageSize={5}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
    checkboxSelection
  />
</div>
);
}
```

You can learn many more about Material UI Tables here:
[Material UI Tables](https://mui.com/components/tables/#main-content)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not using any of those, I'm using what's my code shows in the description,<MUIDataTable>

Comment: @AymenLMIR I believe the point of this answer is what you do need to do i.e. use `const columns = [` - see where it has a set of attributes such as `align: "left", `

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss thx for your response, but i'm using <Muidatatble/> columns, it only supports (name,label,options) and align is not a property